# 2-natural equivalence

Tags: 2-categories

Let $ F, G: X\to Y $ be 2-functors. Is the following statement true?

" A 2-natural transformation $ \alpha : F\to G $ is a 2-natural equivalence if and only if each component $ \alpha _ K $ is an equivalence of $Y$. "

I am almost sure that this is true if $Y=CAT$. But I couldn't see if it is true for a general $Y$.

I am looking for a answer when $ \alpha $ is a pseudonatural transformation too.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it is not true even if $Y = CAT$. The counterexample came from an observation of Kan extensions.

Let $\nabla 2 $ be the localization of the category $ 2 $ (w.r.t. all morphisms). And let $ \ast $ be the category with only one object and only one morphism (the identity). If S is the 2-category consisting of a parallel pair of arrows ($\alpha : a\to b $, $ \beta : a\to b $); consider the following 2-functors

$X: S\to Cat $
and
$Y: S\to Cat $

such that $ X(a)= Y(a)= Y(b) = \ast $, $ X(b) = \nabla 2 $, $Y(\alpha ) = Y (\beta ) $ and $ X(\alpha ) \not = X( \beta ) $.

There is a $2$-natural transformation $ \varepsilon : X\to Y $ such that every component of $ \varepsilon $ is an equivalence. However, there is no $2$-natural transformation $Y\to X $. In particular, $ \varepsilon $ is not a 2-natural equivalence.

Comment: The statement is true for pseudonatural transformations though. A pseudonatural transformation between pseudofunctors is an equivalence if and only if it is entry-wise an  equivalence. See the nLab entry  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudonatural+transformation